# Any way to get Nvidia Optimus card working on 14.04.1?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

My Nvidia graphic card has Optimus technology and as far as I can see it is not working, not even recognized.
On system settings details it says Intel Haswell Mobile on graphic section. Also on startup I get a screen saying unknown chipset with some numbers which seems to be associated with this issue.
Is there any way to make it work on 14.04.1? I have seen Bumblebee suggestions but does it work on the last version of Ubuntu?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works (at least for me on an Asus computer Nvidia Optimus with U 14.04).

[Try this excellent guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433)

HTH

Comment: I installed Bumblebee following the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu as suggested in the guide you shared. Now when I go "optirun firefox &" it says: ":~$ [  340.417853] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[  340.417912] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled."